# Nestjs: Property doesn't exists in Mongoose document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am using Nestjs with Mongoose, and face some challenges with this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Key, KeyDocument } from '@app/mongo';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class KeysService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Key.name) private readonly KeysModel: Model<KeyDocument>
  ) {
    this.test()
  }

  private async test(): Promise<void> {
    await this.KeysModel
      .find()
      .cursor()
      .eachAsync(async (key) => {
        key.token = 'lllsdfsd';
        await key.save()
      })
  }
}
```

Somehow, my service, within `.eachAsync` can't see document types.

[image: No types for docs]

The schema file is typical for Nestjs docs:

```js
import { Document } from "mongoose";
import { Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

export type KeyDocument = Key & Document;

export class Key {
  @Prop()
  _id: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  secret: string;

  @Prop()
  token: string;

  @Prop()
  expired_in: number;

  @Prop()
  tags: string[];
}

export const KeysSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Key);
```

Why such a problem can be, and how to solve it?

> *I have also tried to make my own special interface. with exactly the same fields as schema and add it to `export type KeyDocument = Key & Document<IKey>;`* but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the solution was trivial, and I start panicking too soon. I just forgot to declare interface type for arg in the `eachAsync` function.

```
await this.KeysModel
  .find()
  .cursor()
  .eachAsync(async (key: KeyDocument): Promise<void> => {
     key.token = 'lllsdfsd';
     await key.save()
  })
```